# issue in getting data in listview using get API calling android

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

**Issue in Getting API data in listview**,

api is calling but list not shown in listview, when i dedug program it's run till  `call.enque` method after this line it break on throw on last line

**i want this response in my Listview but i face issue i don't know where i mistake**

This is my Get API response

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "",
"user": [
{
"id": 1,
"username": "Admin",
"email": "admin@gmail.com",
"role": "Administrator"
},
{
"id": 2,
"username": "Lawyer",
"email": "lawyer@gmail.com",
"role": "Lawyer"
},
{
"id": 3,
"username": "Driver",
"email": "driver@gmail.com",
"role": "Driver"
}
]
}
```

**activity_main**

```
  <ListView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/ls"/>
```

**Interface class api.java**

```
public interface api {
String BASE_URL = "https://efce0212.ngrok.io/api/";
@GET("user")
Call<List<User>> getHeroes();
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.ls);
    getHeroes();
}

public void getHeroes() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(api.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    api api = retrofit.create(api.class);


    Call<List<User>> call = api.getHeroes();


    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
            final List<User> userList = response.body();

            final String[] user = new String[userList.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {


                user[i] = "Sucess:" + userList.get(i).getSucess() + "\n" + "message" + userList.get(i).getMessage() + "\n" + userList.get(i).getUserData();
            }

            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, user));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

**Pojo USER.JAVA**

```
public class User {
private String sucess;
private String message;
public UserData[] userData;

//UserData  userData  = new UserData();

public User(String sucess, String message, UserData[] userData) {
    this.sucess = sucess;
    this.message = message;
    //this.userData = userData;
    this.userData = userData;
}

public String getSucess() {
    return sucess;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public UserData[] getUserData() {
    return userData;
}
}
```

**UserData.class**

```
public class UserData {
public String  id;
public String name;
public String email;
public String role;
}
```

Comment: Please add the error/Issue which u have faced

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha  i didn't get any error, issue is API data is not shown in listview

Comment: Do u need the customer adapter or spinner

Comment: no i don't need spinner or custom adapter, just want data in list

Comment: remove final from final String[] user = new String[userList.size()]; because after initialized with final you cant modify it.

Comment: @aasifghanchi ..Is your problem is resolved ?

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha no same issue

Comment: @aasifghanchi Have u tried my solution below?

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha yes i tried, but same issue not getting any response

Comment: @aasifghanchi What error u are facing on my code

Comment: Remove this line             final List<User> userList = response.body();
from urs code and try below solution

Comment: when i remove `List<User> userList = response.body();` this line, then  error in `userlist`

Comment: User is your model not an Arraylist u can try these way like User userModel = response.body();     List< UserData > userList  = userModel. getUserData();

Comment: @aasifghanchi Does ur problem resolved? Have tried my updated solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a LinearLayout manager to your List View.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    listView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see

> ```
> {
> "success": true,
> "message": "",
> "user": [
> {
> "id": 1,
> "username": "Admin",
> "email": "admin@gmail.com",
> "role": "Administrator"
> },
> {
> "id": 2,
> "username": "Lawyer",
> "email": "lawyer@gmail.com",
> "role": "Lawyer"
> },
> {
> "id": 3,
> "username": "Driver",
> "email": "driver@gmail.com",
> "role": "Driver"
> }
> ]
> }
> ```

your response is a `User` object but as I see

> `call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>()`

you expect a list of `User`s as response which doesn't make sense.

I hope changing `call` response type to `User` can fix it. As this:

```
Call<User> call = api.getHeroes();

call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

       ...

    }
});
```

Comment: after applying this error in this line `final List <User> userList = response.body();` what should i write instead of this line

Comment: You have an object of type `User` which is your `response.body()` .

Then you can use `response.body().getUserDate()` and use `UserData` objects as you wish.